# Will solving the KKT conditions solve the quadratic program?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, optimal-control, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

I'm trying to learn quadratic programming and it has always been difficult to me, until I found this video about how to solve a quadratic problem with quadratic programming. Only necessary theory is applied. 
 [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DMYE9sBWdw)

I tried to summarize the methodic. First build the objective function on the standard form. This is what the professor in the video shows:

$$\bigtriangledown (x^TQx + c^Tx)$$

I have seen objective functions like this too. Let me know if its matter to have the $\frac{1}{2}$ included or not
$$\bigtriangledown (\frac{1}{2}x^TQx + c^Tx)$$

Anyway. When the objective function is created, then it need to be subject to constraints. In this case, the professor in the video shows these constraints.

$$Ax\leq b$$
$$x \geq 0$$

He began to create the KKT-conditions based on the objective function and the constraints.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2Q & A^T  & -I_n  &0 \\ 
 A&  0&  0& I
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
u\\ 
v\\ 
s
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-c\\ 
b
\end{bmatrix}$$

Here we know $Q, A, I_n, I, c, b$ and we want to find $x$.

**Questions:**

- 1:
  All I need to do is to find the KKT-conditions and solve it and then find $x$. There is nothing more in Quadratic programming? Just like that? Once we find the vector $x$, then we have found the solution that minimize the objective function and also taking account on the constraints?
- 2:
  Do I need to prove that the objective function is convex for every solving? Or is it enough to check if $Q \ge 0$

The reason why I'm asking, is because the video seems to be so simple and easy and I got a bible at home about quadratic programming. It's huge math compare to this above.

**Edit:**

I made a small test but I cannot confirm if it works. All I can see is that some $x$ values is less than $0$. Notice that I just starting to put in some random values. I don't really have an working example to look at.

```
% Q and c matrix for objective function
Q = [2 2; 3 4];
c = [1; 2];

% Constraints
A = [1 2; 1 3];
b = [2;2];


% Zeros and identiy matrices 
In = eye(size(A',1));
I =  eye(size(A,1));
zer0 = zeros(size(A,1));
Azero = zeros(size(A,1), size(A', 2));
Inzero = zeros(size(A,1), size(In, 2));

% Solve Lx = v
L = [2*Q, A', -In, zer0;
    A, Azero, Inzero, I];       
v = [-c; b];
x = linsolve(L, v)(1:length(Q));

% Compute the value J
J = x'*Q*x + c'*x

% Output:
J =  1.5996

>> x
x =

  -0.55481
   0.72450
```

Comment: The linear system you have written above is not, by itself, the KKT conditions. Notice that it has more unknowns than equations, so does not give a unique solution! You also need to satisfy the feasibility conditions $x\ge0,u\ge0,v\ge0,s\ge0$, and the complementarity conditions $(Ax-b)^Tu=0,x^Tv=0$ (I hope I got those right...) Solving all of these together with the linear system you have gives you the solution of the QP. That is not so easy as your Matlab code... which is why your bible at home is such huge math.

Comment: @Rahul So this QP-programming can be lots of more equations to solve?

Comment: Equations *and inequalities*. It does not simply reduce to a system of more linear equations.

Comment: @Rahul so to solve the system above, I need to use ?

Comment: A quadratic programming solver, I'd say. A [linear complementarity problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_complementarity_problem) solver will also do.

Comment: @Rahul So you mean that if I want to minimize a convex quadratic function with inequality constraints. I need to first find the langrange multipliers $\lambda$ first? Is there any way to find those?

Comment: @Rahul I understand now that KKT will not solve the system. KKT will check if these 4 conditions are true, then I have found the global minimum solution for the objective function.

Comment: @Rahul Or do you mean that I need to set up some cases with my objective function and check it agains the KKT, without knowing the $\lambda$?

Comment: @Rahul I solved the problem. I implemented qpOASES https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl